# haystack on existing template

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, django-class-based-views

How to implement working SearchView in existing views.py?
I already have CBV, and added in urls.py as /moderate and want to apply search form in it. but always got "Results No results found."

This is my /moderate page with 3 forms, using SearchView and piece of code from tutorial in template.

[image]

And this from /search page, with urls(r'^search/$', include('haystack.urls'))

[image]

urls.py

```
urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
    url(r'^moderate/', Moderate.as_view(), name='moderate'),
]
```

views.py

```
class Moderate(SearchView):

    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Moderate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    #model = Ad
    template_name = 'adapp/ad_moderate.html'
    #template_name = 'search/search.html'

    paginator_class = DiggPaginator
    paginate_by = 10
    ad_type = None
    ad_sub_type = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(Moderate, self).get_queryset().filter(ad_type__isnull=False,
                                                           ad_sub_type__isnull=False)

        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Moderate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = ModerateFilter(self.request.GET)

        return context

    # define method to recieve fields from form, and change data accordings
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        selected = request.POST['selected']
        record = Ad.objects.get(pk=int(selected))
        form = ModerateForm(request.POST, instance=record)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
```

template/ad_moderate.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load i18n url_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="casing">
        <div id="content">

{# filter form, to show only models with moderated=True #}
    <form action="" method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Search</h2>

{# search form right from tutorial #}
    <form method="get" action="">
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        {% if query %}
            <h3>Results</h3>

            {% for result in page.object_list %}
                <p>
                    <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.title }}</a>
                </p>
            {% empty %}
                <p>No results found.</p>
            {% endfor %}

        {% else %}
            {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
        {% endif %}
    </form>

            {% for object in filter %}
{# a lot of template tags and third form to change value of model #}
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="radio" name="moderated" value="True">Accept
                        <br>
                        <input type="radio" name="moderated" value="False">Decline
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ object.id }}"
                        name="selected">
                        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="moderate">
                    </form>
```

search_indexes.py

```
from .models import Ad

class AdIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    def get_model(self):
    # my model, with one search should be
        return Ad
```

templates/search/indexes/app/ad_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.short_desc }}
{{ object.description }}
{{ object.experience }}
{{ object.skills }}
{{ object.name }}
{{ object.city }}
```

Comment: Not much info...is your search engine already running and properly configured?

Comment: yeap, sorry for a lack of info, just now filling with.

Answer (score 0):

```
get_context_data():
    context['search'] = SearchForm(self.request.GET).search()
```

Would solve a problem.

That means, I should create form and send return from .save() method, rather that django-like form instance.

Comment: Please add some explanation your answer!